# Purification of Gaussian states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Let us consider an $n$-mode Gaussian state $\rho_g$ (mixed state) in the Bosonic Fock space $\Gamma(\mathbb{C}^n)$. My question is, can we have a purification of $\rho_g$ which is itself Gaussian? Notice that convex combination of Gaussian states is not Gaussian, in general.

To make it more specific, let us assume that $\rho_g=\rho(\mathbf{l},\mathbf{m};S)$, where $\mathbf{l}$ and $\mathbf{m}$ are position and momentum means and $S$ is the covariance matrix. What would be the means and covariance matrices of the purification, if a Gaussian purification exists.

Can we have a similar result, if the state is an infinite mode Gaussian state? Advanced thanks for any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It is always possible to find a purification of a Gaussian state in terms of a Gaussian state.

This is most easily seen in terms of covariance matrices.  A convenient way of doing so is to bring your covariance matrix into normal form by sympectic transformations. This decouples the system into a set of decoupled normal modes at some temperature, which can be easily purified by entangling each of them with another bosonic mode (i.e., a two-mode squeezed states). Undoing the sympectic transformation yields a covariance matrix for a Gaussian purification of the original state.

More details, including an explicit form for the purification, can be found e.g. in [A. Holevo and R. Werner, *Evaluating capacities of bosonic Gaussian channels*, 
Phys. Rev. A **63**, 032312 (2001)](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9912067).